# Any cable can help me with both display and transferring mouse receiver?

Tags: port, usb-3, displayport, usb-c, usb-controller

I have a monitor with all the ports listed like this:

[image: monitor ports]

My laptop ports are in the photos below:

[image]

On my laptop, Port 1 is USB 3.2 Gen 1 port with PowerShare
Port 2 is Thunderbolt 4.0 port with Power Delivery and DisplayPort
Port 3 is microSD-card slot
Port 4 is USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-C port with DisplayPort 1.4 and PowerDeliver
Port 5 is HDMI 2.1 port

My current setting is I have plugged in all my receivers (mouse, keyboard, controller) to the monitor usb ports, and used a USB upstream cable to connect monitor port 8 and laptop port 1, so all the receivers work for the laptop. I'm also using another HDMI cable to connect monitor port 9 to laptop port 5.

Is there any kind of USB C cable that combine the two cables together?

Comment: We do not recommend hardware on this site. Please read the Help section.

Comment: @music2myear, any website you can redirect me to for this kind of questions?

Comment: No need, the answer is there isn't. There are USB-C cables for that purpose but NOT for your monitor which doesn't have USB-C ports. It should be obvious.

Comment: @ChanganAuto No, it's not obvious at all. Firstly we're power users and our knowledge (and sense of what's obvious) isn't representative of an average user. Secondly, these things actually exist - see my answer.

Comment: @gronostaj A docking station isn't a cable ;) The OP asked for a cable and those also exist, USB-C on both ends, for compatible monitors that then may or may not include USB ports and even other devices like we find in USB-C docking stations. With one as you suggest the OP would be using the exact same cables *plus* the docking station itself with a daisychained USB hub. A pure waste of money if bought for this purpose only.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't see the double USB-C requirement in the question. OP isn't really looking for a cable. They're looking for a solution to their problem: they want to connect the monitor and USB peripherals with a single USB-C plug. For lack of a better word they used the term "cable" and I'm pretty sure they don't mind if there's a plastic box at one end as long as it gets the job done. If they knew what it's called, they wouldn't be asking the question. I could choose to be pedantic about their wording or try to see through it and be helpful.

Comment: @gronostaj The "plastic box" doesn't get the job done and this also should be pretty obvious :) You're missing the point entirely. The Op wants to use one cable instead of two because convenience, whatever. It's simply NOT possible with this monitor. The OP doesn't need the docking station to provide HDMI, their laptop already has one; likewise it already has a USB port to connect to and use the monitor's USB hub. Adding the dock just moves the exact same 2 cables to the dock instead of connecting both directly like they have now.

Comment: @ChanganAuto _"Adding the dock just moves the exact same 2 cables to the dock"_ - yes, exactly. It lets them connect just one USB-C cable to the laptop. Yes, laptop's HDMI is unused, but it was not a requirement to use laptop's built-in HDMI. Actually they asked for _"any kind of USB C cable that combine the two cables together"_. This is it: HDMI and upstream USB combined into a single USB-C.

Comment: *I could choose to be pedantic about their wording or try to see through it and be helpful.* Sorry to say but now you're being pedantic and reading more than what really is there just to "save face". The question is and always has been "Is there any kind of USB C cable that combine the two cables together?" and yes, there is, for **monitors with an upstream USB-C connection!** It's freaking obvious the OP want this feature for this old monitor but that's simply not possible, period. **The OP wants to simplify. Adding a docking station in-between does the exact opposite.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138684/discussion-between-gronostaj-and-changanauto).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a USB-C docking station. [Something like these](https://i-tec.pro/en/shop-window/?kon=USB-C) (*not a recommendation* - first link from Google). Simplest models have an HDMI port + a couple USBs. More advanced ones can also charge the laptop. Before buying one make sure supported display modes fit your needs (eg. some can't drive 4K displays at 60 fps).